# Falha na comunicação com o banco de dados Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, exceção, jdbc

Eu tenho um banco de dados que está na nuvem, pois é de um site que eu e alguns colegas estamos criando e precisei conectá-lo ao Netbeans, eu coloquei o host, o nome do banco, usuario e senha e está tudo certo, porém quando eu vou fazer um SELECT, uma INSERÇÃO de dados ou até mesmo quando quero visualizar as tabelas, a conexão cai e apresenta a excessão:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure.

Se eu executar o comando novamente o mesmo funciona, porém só se tentar novamente loga após ocorrer o erro.

Queria resolver para que não tivesse que executar o comando duas vezes sempre.

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Posta o código do seu pool de conexão senão fica meio dificil responder.